# Android grid view recycle issue

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager

I get an error when i try to use the a recycled gridview every time if convertView != null then i get an error here is my source code.
it will give me an error right at text = (TextView) convertView; in the else statment. I am really lost here, I would just stop recycling the views but then its to heavy on memory and its choppy scrolling

$ here is the imageadapter.java

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout lay;

    ImageView image;
    TextView text;
    if (convertView == null) {
        Log.d("height", "Width = " + width);

        lay = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        image = new ImageView(mContext);
        text = new TextView(mContext);


        //text.setText("This is a test");
        text.setTextSize(14);
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
        text.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int) Math.round(width / 2.0),
                (int) Math.round(width / 8.3));

        textLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        text.setLayoutParams(textLayout);

        MarginLayoutParams textMarginFix = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) text
                .getLayoutParams();
        textMarginFix.setMargins(0, 0, 0, (int) Math.round(width / 45.0));
        text.setLayoutParams(textMarginFix);

        image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int) Math
                .round(width / 2.0), (int) Math.round(width /              2.0)));

        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        //image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        lay.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int) Math
                .round(width / 2.0), (int) Math.round(width / 2.0)));
        lay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shadowimage);
        lay.setPadding(5, 5, 15, 15);
        //lay.setId(mThumbIds[position]);

        //lay.addView(image);
        //lay.addView(text);

    } 
    else
    {
        text = (TextView) convertView;
        image = (ImageView) convertView;
        lay = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
    }

    image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    text.setText("This is a test");

    lay.addView(image);
    lay.addView(text);

     return lay;

}
$here is where i call the imageadapter from another class

    @Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
   View contentView;        
   switch (position) {
    case 0:
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View contentView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_grid_view,   null);
        Display display = mContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();
        float scale = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        GridView gridview = (GridView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(mContext, width, height, scale));
        gridview.setFocusable(true);
        gridview.requestFocus();
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(contentView, 0);
        break;
...return contentView
```

Comment: But no I am not, these images are stored in the application

Comment: I see. I would suggest to rework code as per the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`convertView` is the view that entirely represents **one** item in your `GridView`. If that is a `TextView`, it will be a `TextView`, if it is an entire layout, you will receive the entire layout and so on.

So how do you know and define what is "the view that represents one item"? Simple, it is whatever you create when `convertView == null` and then `return` from `getView`.

Simply you are receiving a used item and you are just modifying it to update it to the appropriate content. So you should utilize type casting to get this `View` you receive in a format you want.

Code like below will get you what you want without redoing things you don't need to do (aka you do not need to re-add child `Views` from a `convertView`, only a new view):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout lay;
    ImageView image;
    TextView text;

    if (convertView == null) {
        // Setup your 'item view'
        lay = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        image = new ImageView(mContext);
        text = new TextView(mContext);

        // Do all your customizing stuff (aka size, color, format, padding layout params)

        lay.addView(image, 0);
        lay.addView(text, 1);
    } else {
        lay = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        image = (ImageView) lay.getChildAt(0);
        text = (TextView) lay.getChildAt(1);
    }

    // Set content for your image and text

    return lay;
}
```

Comment: OK now I understand what's going on here thank you very much. The code is working great. Unfortunately for me the scrollbar on the gridview is still chopped up, not smooth. This must be some other reason, it may be due to the image getting scaled down, which cause's slow loading

Comment: Yea, you are entering a lot of big issues with GridViews that I have battled with for a while. How many items are displayed on the screen at once? And what sizes are your images? There is a LOT of work in moving this from what it is now into something that scrolls smoothly.[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) is a good place to start. From there you will have to make some design choices about what you really need (aka is it bad to load and resize all images into a cache straight up, or will that take too long, etc, etc)

Comment: Yea I load around 20 images, each are image is around 500px width and height. I tried loading images that were smaller and it worked perfectly. So I will have to find another method to scaling these images. gridview is not my friend

Comment: So 20 images in total? Or 20 images per page at a time? Because to be honest, GridView could really work quite well. If its 20 images total, a progress bar that launches an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to resize all your images and save them to a cache and [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)), removes the progressbar from your layout and adds the gridview, would be a perfect solution.

Comment: 20 per gridview (later I will have a activity with 50+ photos from a server not for this activity). You nailed it, I was just checking the documentation on caching images right now. I think thats my solution.

Answer (score 0):

**[ADDITION]**

Further, you have the code

```
image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
text.setText("This is a test");

lay.addView(image);
lay.addView(text);

return lay;
```

outside the if and the else, what this means is that you are trying to add a subview EVERY TIME a cell's view is asked for.  You really only need to add views to lay within the if portion of your routine.

**[ORIGINAL]**
Most likely convertView is your parent, and all other views are sub to it.  In your else clause, all you do is set each one to the SAME EXACT THING.  How can the convertView be three completely different things all at once.

Most likely it needs to be:

```
text = (TextView) convertView.SomeTextViewSubToConvertView;
image = (ImageView) convertView.SomeImageViewSubToConvertView;
lay = (RelativeLayout) convertView.SomeRelativeLayoutSubToConvertView;
```

Comment: @user1486574 - I have added to my answer!

Comment: Thanks again, I am still having trouble with it, I tried assigning ids to the individual views but its still having problems at the same spot. I am trying to follow this example from google http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: I tried this image.setId(2); for each view and then in the else statment it tried this image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(2);

Comment: Ok I got it! thank you it because of both reason's you said, first needed to setId's to the view and then find by their id. And then i was adding the view's to parent view even if they were already there. Thank you so much for you help!